# Creating pdf files in App Engine Cron Job

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pdf, cron

I am using Python 2.7 and Reportlab to create .pdf files for display/print in my app engine system.  I am using ndb.Model to store the data if that matters.

I am able to produce the equivalent of a bank statement for a single client on-line.  That is; the user clicks the on-screen 'pdf' button and the .pdf statement appears on screen in a new tab, exactly as it should.

However, I have to produce multiple statements overnight to be printed and posted the next morning.  One (largish) .pdf would be fine.

So, I can produce the pdf but how do I get it back to the user for printing?  I had thought of email but the size may (not sure) be too great and I'm not sure if this has too much risk for financial information.

At this stage statements for up to 20 clients per night (a total of 30-60 pages) must be produced but this number will increase to at least 200 statements per night during 2018.  Any thoughts or ideas for me?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to save the generated PDFs [into Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/googlecloudstorageclient/read-write-to-cloud-storage#writing_to_cloud_storage) (GCS) and create a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) for each saved PDF which you could then send by email to the respective users. They can then download the PDFs using those emailed URLs and print them.

Or you can dynamically serve the saved PDFs on-demand, via actions on your app in response to subsequent user requests (view/print) etc.